# What is merge and timestampsInSnapshot in the firebase?

Tags: firebase

I am getting this error at the console; "You are overriding the original host. If you did not intend to override your settings, use {merge: true}." When ı add this code line it's solved

```
db.settings({ timestampsInSnapshot: true, merge: true });
```

Notice: timeInSnapshot settings don't relevant above error. Just ı ask what does mean it? and ı didn't write any other codes.

Answer (score 9):

It seems that is not an error, but a warning.

[image]

According to [Version 8.6.3 release notes](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/js#version_863_-_may_27_2021):

> Firestore will throw a warning message when `settings()` is used to override the original value of `host` without also setting `{merge: true}`.

You can also check [Firestore settings documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Settings) to better understand the use of `host` and `merge`:

- `host`: The hostname to connect to.
- `merge`: Whether to merge the provided settings with the existing settings. If set to true, the settings are merged with existing settings. If set to false or left unset, the settings replace the existing settings.

So it seems that without setting `merge: true`, you would be overriding the `host`, even if you were not setting it explicitly in that call.

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer